# In Browser console ..The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true'

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, socket.io

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQb0Bxp' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

in Node js (Backend)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

 

  
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:8100",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
}
});


io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log("A user connected");

    // socket.emit('test event','my connection');

    socket.on('test event',(data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('test event','my connection');
    })

})

 
// console.log(app)
server.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("socket io server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

in angular

websocker.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import  * as io   from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebSocketService {
  socket:any;
  readonly url = "ws://localhost:3000";



  constructor() {
    console.log(io,"io")
    this.socket = io.connect(this.url,{});
   }


  listen(eventName:string){
    return new Observable((subscriber)=>{
      this.socket.on(eventName , (data)=>{
        subscriber.next(data);
      });
    })
  }

  emit(eventName:string,data:any){
      this.socket.emit(eventName,data);
  }


}
```

Comment: Did below code worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io (3.x) the migration documents are fairly helpful.

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your backend/nodejs code

**Instead of**

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:8100",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
}
});
```

**please use below code**

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){  
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','* or secific')  
    next(); 
})

const io = require("socket.io")(server);
```